# Wait on AWT Event Dispatcher Thread Thread with Multi-Threading

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, awt

Is there a way to block the execution on the EDT, with still having a vivid gui?

I noticed that JDialog/JOptionPane has something similar, when calling setVisible(true).

Why would i need this?

My Class should satisfy to following interface:

```
interface Quitable {
   boolean quit();
}
```

My Class needs a implementation like this:

```
class MyApp implements Quitable {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
   // ...
   public boolean quit() {
           FuturTask<Boolean> futureTask = new FutureTask<Boolean>(saveJob);
           executor.execute(futureTask);
           // TODO: keep gui vivid
           boolean saveResult = futureTask.get();
           return saveResult;
   }
   // ...
}
```

I need to return the result of the save process (which may take some time and may fail). Or would you suggest another solution? Thanks for any ideas. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dialog` causes the an event loop to be executed whilst it is blocking. There is a filter that allows certain events through such as repaint requests, invocation events and events to the dialog window. The API for this is not exposed.

There was a library ([Foxtrot](http://foxtrot.sourceforge.net/), IIRC), that used a hack on `Dialog` to expose this behaviour.

I would strongly suggest structuring your program in such a way that this is not required. It's a very procedural rather than event-driven organisation. So queue your task on another thread (possible a thread pool/executor service or GUI-like event-loop), and then update the GUI with `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater`.

Comment: Presentation about the JDialog-Hack: http://www.futuretek.com/presents/foxtrot/KeepingYourSwingApplicationsResponsiveUsingFoxTrot.ppt

Answer (score 1):

JDialog does not block the execution of EDT, EDT ignores events except jDialog's event when it is opened as modal.

I do suggest you to show progressbar as modal, before calling quit method.